# Grabbing information from textbox and putting it in label?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, concatenation

Basically I'm writing an application for school and I can't figure something out.

I'm trying to grab information entered in textboxes. I'm trying to grab a name, an age, and a movie title from three separate textboxes, and put them into a single label like this:

"Name" is "age," her favourite film is "movie title."

after clicking the "Show" button.

I know it's a click event for the show button, but I can't quite figure out how to make the concatenated message.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder, it is much more efficient than standard string concat:

```
Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

sbText.Append(txtName.Text).Append(" is ").Append(txtAge.Text).Append(", her favourite film is ").Append(txtMove.Text)

lblLabel.Text = sbText.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `&` operator to concatenate strings:

```
Label1.text = TextBox1.text & TextBox2.text & TextBox3.text
```

This is less efficient than StringBuilder, but that shouldn't matter because a user entering data in a textbox takes about 10,000 times longer per character than this concatenation.